# Substring in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am looking for a way to get substring of a String. I am looking for an equivalent of this Java method. I am ok to use libraries but did not find it in solidity-stringutils.

```
public String substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html?highlight=substring#what-are-some-examples-of-basic-string-manipulation-substring-indexof-charat-etc) states, that there is no built in string manipulation available. Nevertheless, we can convert a string to a byte array and do the manipulation manually:

```
function substring(string str, uint startIndex, uint endIndex) constant returns (string) {
    bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
    bytes memory result = new bytes(endIndex-startIndex);
    for(uint i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        result[i-startIndex] = strBytes[i];
    }
    return string(result);
}
```

Disclaimer: this method works for ASCII strings, but not for characters that are encoded with multiple bytes in UTF-8 (e.g. umlaute).

Comment: Here's a fiddle so you can play around with it: https://ethfiddle.com/-IaBg6dld7

Comment: Thank you, Nicci and James for making the community better. I was not aware of ethfiddle. Very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

**Update for Solidity 0.8.0 versions**

```
function substring(string memory str, uint startIndex, uint endIndex) public pure returns (string memory ) {
    bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
    bytes memory result = new bytes(endIndex-startIndex);
    for(uint i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        result[i-startIndex] = strBytes[i];
    }
    return string(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter, gas-efficient answer without **for** loops:

```
function trim(string calldata str, uint start, uint end) external pure returns(string memory) {
    return str[start:end];
}
```

This takes a string and `start` and `end` positions and returns a substring.